# EL equivalent of <%= object.method(parameter) %> in WAS 8?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, el, websphere-8

The documentation says parameters are supported but the example uses `hl` and `#` which are unknown to me where I use c: and $ instead of this which is from the docs:

`<h:inputText value="#{userNumberBean.userNumber('5')}">`

All I know about $ vs # in EL is that is has to do with rvalue and lvalue which I can need a further explanation when to use the # style. I'm looking for how an EL expression of typ $... can take a parameter and how to call non-getters non-setters with a parameter for example fetching a constant static string from a bean in the request context.

What does # do compared to $? How do I use parameters in EL if I want to use the $?
The scriptlets I want to migrate to EL are something like `<%= Constants.CONSTANT %>`and `<%= object.method(parameter) %>` that I want to do in EL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#{}` syntax is supposed to be used in [the Java EE's MVC framework JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) only. See also [Difference between JSP EL, JSF EL and Unified EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812755/difference-between-jsp-el-jsf-el-and-unified-el). Just stick to `${}` syntax in old JSP.

As to invoking methods with arguments, this is introduced in Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2. WAS 8 is a Servlet 3.0 container, so it should support it out the box. You only need to make sure that your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 3.0 specification version. Otherwise the container will run in fallback modus matching the version indicated by `web.xml`. The proper Servlet 3.0 `web.xml` declaration look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

This way the `${object.method(param)}` must work.

Referencing constants in EL is a different story. This will be [introduced](http://java.net/projects/el-spec/pages/StaticField) in the upcoming EL 3.0, which is part of the future Java EE 7 / Servlet 3.1 (and likely the future WAS 9 or 10 would support it). There are solutions in flavor of custom taglibs or by keeping them in a `Map`, all explained in detail in this answer: [How to reference constants in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732608/how-to-reference-constants-in-el)

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: Many thanks BalusC, it's working: `${person.getPersonTyp(GrunduppgifterConstants.persontypSokande).ordNr}` is working.