# how to check radio button gender variable in jstl using c:if

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, crud

try to build simple crud application in Netbeanse ide.

In the edit record page how do i Display corresponding gender.

if i was using **scriptlet** to write the code as follows in jsp page:

```
 <% if(rm.getGender().equals("Male")){ %>

 <input type="radio" name="Gender" tabindex="" value="Male" checked="checked"> Male 
 <input type="radio" name="Gender" tabindex="" value="Female">Female

   <%}else{ %>
          <input type="radio" name="Gender" tabindex="" value="Male"> Male 
         <input type="radio" name="Gender" tabindex="" value="Female" checked="checked">Female

    <% } %>
```

**Now my jstl code** :

```
                        <c:if test="${user.gender}"  var="Male">
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked"/>Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female     
                        </c:if> 
  <c:if test="${user.gender}" var="Female">
       <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked"/>Male <input        type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" checked="checked"/>Female   
                         </c:if>
```

i did'nt get desired output. 
any  suggesion plz.

Thanks to **Mr.Dhruv pal** I got the Answer:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${(user.gender).equalsIgnoreCase('Male')}">
                              <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"     checked="checked"/>Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female </td>    
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise >
                                   <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked"/>Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" checked="checked"/>Female </td>         
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: try using c:choose it works in place of if else

Comment: thanks dhruv pal: but it is not enough for a Beginner...

Comment: have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219267/how-do-i-do-the-equivalent-of-a-java-if-else-block-using-jstl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219267/how-do-i-do-the-equivalent-of-a-java-if-else-block-using-jstl)

Comment: for checking equality look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189963/jstl-if-tag-for-equal-strings] link