# c:if tag is not working correctly in case of true

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm trying to use `c:if` tag but it is not displaying anything in case of true. What should I do to display any text when `if` condition is true.
Here is my xhtml code

```
<html>
  <body>

    <c:if test="#{fileMB.per.getFirstName()}='gul'}" >
        <h:outputLabel for="user" value="#{logMB.userExists.getFirstName()}"/>
    </c:if>

  </body>
</html>
```

per is the scope variable of login person...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things wrong with your code:

1. You're using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator. Not to mention that you really shouldn't be using the comparison operator with strings. So your comparison should read instead

   ```
   #{fileMB.per.getFirstName().equals('gul')}}
   ```
2. You shouldn't be using JSTL tags with facelets, unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) and change your code to be

   ```
   <h:outputLabel for="user" rendered="#{fileMB.per.getFirstName().equals('gul')}}" value="#{logMB.userExists.getFirstName()}"/>
   ```

Of course the overall effectiveness of this approach is still based on picking the right bean scope (read: `@ViewScoped`)

**Read**

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your condition within JSTL tag.

`<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>`

See more in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm

Also you have close } tag without open tag in your condition, # instead of $ and you should compare strings with double equals ==

See more in [JSTL if tag for equal strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10189963/jstl-if-tag-for-equal-strings)